# Access Tumblr RSS Feed from UWP App after GDPR

Tags: uwp, rss

So, for a few days now, my RSS Reader App goes into a tizzy when accessing Tumblr.
SyndicationClient throws an exception on tumblr RSS "DTD is prohibited". Which is caused by Tumblr redirecting to a Web Page asking for GDPR-related consent.

I have a WebView in my app where the user can give their consent. Unfortunately,  SyncationClient seems to have stopped (since the last Windows & UWP Update) using the cookies placed by that WebView control inside the app ... which means I have no way to tell the SyndicationClient "Shhh, it's ok"...

Ideas? I tried using the UWP Toolkit RssParser on a string, but I simply cannot get the actual RSS content, as the cookie is not placed.

Am quite frustrated by now.

Comment: How did you set the cookies for the SyncationClient in your code? Please post some code here.

Comment: I cannot set a cookie, as I do not know what cookie the RSS Feed Provider needs... and I am sure as hell not going to copy any cookie the web sites drops... that feels like very shaky ground.

Comment: I have no idea why you guys force an exception on poor unsuspecting web developers, or why you are separating the cookie containers within a single app.... that worked before, why change what works??? (assuming by your By-Line that you are related to Microsoft)

Comment: I used the UWP official [Syndication sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/Syndication) and a RSS [url](https://planetcorgi.tumblr.com/rss) from Tumblr official site to test. It worked well.

Comment: My OS build is 17134, the project's target/min version is 17134

Comment: Sure, are you trying to access it from within GDPR? Coz Tumblr in their infinite wisdom put a HTTP301 in from of the RSS resource to redirect to their Consent Form, which SyndicationClient really really does not like.

Comment: At this moment, I am testing replacing the whole of SyndicationClient with a xDocument infrastructure, so that I can get to the actual content by myself and then parse it. What a Waste of Time.

Comment: The underlying issue is that SyndicationClient does not expose a Parse(string rsscontents) method, as Toolkit.Parsers.Rss.RssParser does. I am sure that method is in there, as the components needs to get a rss string downloaded and then parsed, it is simple not exposed, for whatever reason. I am now forced to recreate the whole logic for dealing with ATOM and RSS feed because of that. Fun!

Comment: I also parse the Rss feed myself.

Comment: Thanks, Bite, though so by now. What I do is try to use SyndicationClient. If that runs into a problem, I am using RssParser. If that fails, I fall back to xDocument. Yeah, efficiency!

Answer (score 0):

In case others have this problem, all you need to do is set the useragent to Baiduspider

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Baiduspider");
```

that will prevent redirecting to GDPR page.

Comment: Interesting, will check it out. Mind you, very little JS in UWP apps...